# Null pointer Exception while transferring data

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

Hi I am trying to mak an application where book is issued to a person based on book id.Each person can have a maximum of 3 books issued on his name but having error on this function while creating table.Can anyone help me find it.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            deleteDatabse();
             String BookTable = "create table if not exists " +BOOK_DETAILS + " ( " + BOOK_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                        + BOOK_NAME + " text not null unique, "
                        + TYPE + " text, "
                        + AUTHOR + " text, "
                        + DATE + " text);";

                db.execSQL(BookTable);


                String personTable = "create table if not exists " +PERSON + " ( " + PERSON_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                        + PERSON_NAME + " text not null, "
                        + PHONE + " text, "
                        + BOOK_ID + " text,"
                                + " FOREIGN KEY("+TRIP_ID +") REFERENCES BOOK_Details(Book_Id));";
                db.execSQL(personTable);


        }
```

Comment: what is at "at com.example.test.TripHistoryActivity.onCreate(TripHistoryActivity.java:49)" ??

Comment: Show your **TripHistoryActivity** class.

Comment: I have added TripHistoryActivity class.what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Does your layout file `trip_history.xml` include a `ListView` with id `zone_list`? I think the problem is there.

**Edit:**

Actually there is another problem in your code. `ArrayAdapter` does not accept null `ArrayList` or a `null` item in the list. In your case your `arrayList_Name` variable is null because you never send it when you start `TripHistoryActivity`.

In MainActivity you are sending a list with the key "lists" like below.

```
list_bundle.putStringArrayList("lists",mArrayList);
```

So you should get it using

```
arrayList_Name = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lists");
```

Comment: Line 49 is listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter) so indeed it seems likely that listView is null as a result of not being found in the active layout.

Comment: Definitely this should be the case. I don't know where the above layout come from. :) Is it the used layout in the question?

Comment: The xml that is posted in my answer states that it is used in MainActivity. tools:context=".MainActivity"

Comment: can you look at the answer now?